# Protractor: launch chrome with network throttling enabled

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, google-chrome-devtools

The network throttling feature from Chrome DevTools is available in ChromeDriver-2.26+ according to [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=984). How can I specify this in our protractor config file?

Based on searching around, I've tried variations of a couple things in the config file. I've added a `networkConnectionEnabled` property and a `prefs` block to chromeOptions, as below. (Note that I didn't do them both at the same time.)

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'networkConnectionEnabled': {'type': 'GPRS'},
        'chromeOptions': {
            args: [
                '--lang=en',
                '--window-size=1280,1024'
            ],
            prefs: {
                'net.throttling_enabled': 'true,50,20'
            }
        }
    }
],
```

The second option I tried based on what I found [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc) (line 1983). None of these change the behavior of the protractor run, which when I manually test and set the throttling triggers a certain condition in my code.

Edit: also tried adding something like this underchromeOptions: mobileEmulation: `{networkConnectionEnabled: true, networkThrottle: '2G'}`

Comment: If i remember correctly, throttling is available only when the mobile emulation is activated.

Comment: @FlorentB. I tried something like that (see edit), but still not sure I set it up right.

Comment: Network throttling is now detached from Device Mode and is capable of operating at all times.

Answer (score 6):

According to [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-3.4.0) APIs for manipulating network emulation in Chrome were added in Selenium 3.4.0. And they are available in Protract 5.2.0 or newer.

Network conditions can be configured like below:

```
browser.driver.setNetworkConditions({
    offline: false,
    latency: 5, // Additional latency (ms).
    download_throughput: 500 * 1024, // Maximal aggregated download throughput.
    upload_throughput: 500 * 1024 // Maximal aggregated upload throughput.
});
```

This code should be placed in `protractor.conf.js` inside `onPrepare` function.