# "setNetworkConditions" in protractor e2e tests says not a function

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to use the

```
driver.setNetworkConditions({ offline : true });
```

in my code, but it says that `Failed: _protractor.browser.driver.setNetworkConditions is not a function`.

Here is my code to access it.

```
     import { browser } from 'protractor';

        describe('disable browser network', () => {
            "use strict";
            let browserA = browsers.a;
            it('should disable chrome network', () => {
                browserA.ignoreSynchronization = true;
                browser.driver.setNetworkConditions({ offline: true });
                //..... my other functionality here
            });
           afterAll(() => {
           browserA.quit();
           });
        });
```

[image: stack trace message from jasmine:protractor]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44706831/6205848

Comment: @HaC I actually want this in my test case not at configuration level. so it is not a duplicate. Also I am unable to access this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this, actually I just had to update my npm protractor package globally

```
npm install protractor -g
```

and one more thing was to update the package version of protractor to `5.2.0` in `package.json` and again run the `npm install` command to update the `node_modules`

Then this thing work very well.

```
browser.driver.setNetworkConditions({
            offline: true, //I needed to set it offline intentionally
            latency: 150,
            download_throughput: 450 * 1024,
            upload_throughput: 150 * 1024
        });
```